# html5 drag and drop - items.webkitGetAsEntry() method doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, html

hello i am trying to drag and drop files into my filesystem using chrome, but i get the following error in the console:

```
var dnd = new DnDFileController('body', function(files, e) {
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; ++i) {
      traverseFileTree(item.webkitGetAsEntry());
**Uncaught TypeError: Object #<DataTransferItem> has no method 'webkitGetAsEntry'**
    }
  });
```

i also tried to add the method in the loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();; ++i) {
      traverseFileTree(item);
    }
```

the error is like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<DataTransferItem> has no method 'webkitGetAsEntry' app.js:513
(anonymous function) app.js:513
DnDFileController.drop dnd.js:27
```

the DNDFileController.drop code is the following:

```
this.drop = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    el_.classList.remove('dropping');

    onDropCallback(e.dataTransfer.files, e);
  };
```

but i get the same error, any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably you're using this DnDFileController - http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/filesystem/filer.js/demos/js/dnd.js .  So first off, I've got your code to a testable state as:

```
function DnDFileController(selector, onDropCallback) {
  var el_ = document.querySelector(selector);

  this.dragenter = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    el_.classList.add('dropping');
  };

  this.dragover = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  this.dragleave = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    //el_.classList.remove('dropping');
  };

  this.drop = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    el_.classList.remove('dropping');
    onDropCallback(e.dataTransfer.files, e);
  };

  el_.addEventListener('dragenter', this.dragenter, false);
  el_.addEventListener('dragover', this.dragover, false);
  el_.addEventListener('dragleave', this.dragleave, false);
  el_.addEventListener('drop', this.drop, false);
};

var dnd = new DnDFileController('body', function(files, e) {
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; ++i) {
      if (item.kind == 'file') {
          debugger
          console.log(item.webkitGetAsEntry());
      }
    }
  });
```

Now, checking the state of item in the debugger, in Chrome 20.0.1132.27 beta, it is only exposing those properties and methods which are in the current spec[1] - ie, item.kind, item.type, item.getAsString(callback), and item.getAsFile().  DataTransferItem.webkitGetAsEntry() is not exposed.  As far as I can tell[2], Chrome wasn't supposed to be exposing their proposed webkitGetAsEntry yet, and after having it turned on for just one week[3], they turned its switch back off.  So at the moment, it isn't enabled unless you use whatever flags to enable it[4].

Once you enable it, it also looks like its intended, like getAsString, to be used with a callback, not just as a getter.  See example in [5]:

```
    var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      if (items[i].kind == 'file') {
          items[i].webkitGetAsEntry(function(entry) {
          displayEntry(entry.name + (entry.isDirectory ? ' [dir]' : ''));
          ...
        });
      }
    }
```

Note that they also are wrapping it in a protective check that file[i] is actually a file; this is in my test code above, but missing in your code.

But if you're just trying to access the files, is there a reason you want to use this experimental method?  It's a pretty simple loop to use a FileReader to read the file, then Blob-ify it, then store it in a local FileSystem...  and all those methods are far less experimental and new.

Refs:

[1] http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#the-datatransferitem-interface

[2] http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/118507

[3] http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129702

[4] https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87457

[5] http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-whatwg-archive/2012Apr/0078.html

======================================================

UPDATE 7/26/2012:

This method has now had the flags requirement removed, and is available for general use with the release of Chrome 21 on 7/23/12.  However, for the use case described here, the above is much simpler to implement, and better fits the needs, as there was no need to also be able to read entire directories at the same time.

Comment: how would i activate the flag? i saw that thread before, not very helpful =/ i need it to drag and drop files into my filesystem. i would really appreciate if you could provide an example.

Comment: So far as I can see, there is no runtime flag yet.  It looks like DATA_TRANSFER_ITEMS and FILE_SYSTEM both have to be enabled in the build flags, and at the moment, they are only enabled in Chromium.  Ie, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=87457 and https://github.com/gavinp/git.webkit.org/commit/fbed3bfce66f7f750924cb6eab72870a83a559fe .  The original commit didn't add a flag, and the patch commit only disabled it without build flags being enabled.  I see no runtime flags added which would allow you to turn this on in Chrome at runtime.

Comment: By the way, you don't need this method in order to d&d files into your filesystem.  You can easily use FileReader, and send the file to yourFileSystem.root.getFile, along with createWriter, and the file is written into the file system.  I'm doing just this - writing dropped files to a temporary local filesystem - in a userscript I'm currently working on.  See "WRITING TO A FILE" at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/ for info.

Comment: It will write anything you give it, including pdf.  A Blob only cares that you're giving it binary or text content, and a FileSystem only cares that you're giving it either a File or a Blob.  That's it.  You could give it an AAC file, a XLS file, a PDF, or whatever else; they're still all files, and thus, still all valid blobs.

Comment: thank you so much for your help man, i am really grateful i will try it tonight and let you know. =)

Comment: No problem.  If you would, you can show thanks on this site by accepting the answer - ie, clicking on the checkmark thing to the left of the answer, up by the arrows.  :)